# AWS: Allow access to Lambda only, from VPC

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture, serverless

I am stuck with a problem where I have to spin my databases in public subnets because if I try to spin my Lambdas in VPC with ENIs attached, the response time of the lambdas is really horrible. Is there a way to move keep my databases in a private subnet and make lambdas able to talk to them. Plus, Lambdas must be able to communicate on the internet as well. Maybe a security group to allow lambdas only.

Comment: Are you saying that the one Lambda function requires access to both the RDS database and the Internet? Can you tell us more about the delay due to the ENIs? Are they still bad after the first invocation? How often is the function invoked (reserved capacity might help).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you have to follow below steps :

1. Create two subnet group for RDS
2. Assign one of subset of RDS to Lambda also. Lambda will have their own subnet also. After this Lambda will have two subnet.
3. Change Lambda security group outbound rules to reach over internet open for all.

More details can be found here: --https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

https://blog.shikisoft.com/running-aws-lambda-in-vpc-accessing-rds/

Comment: how much of delay the lambda would face when spun up In a VPC?

Comment: generally it get timeout if not able to connect with VPC. as per above steps no delay happen. I have been using this setting from long time never seen any delay